# Image onError Handling in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, youtube, onerror

I am trying to grab the `maxresdefault` of multiple YouTube thumbnails. Some YouTube videos simply don't have a high res thumbnail photo so I want to catch that with an onError prop on an img element. For some reason my function is not triggering when I get the 404 img error. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
class FeaturedVideo extends Component<Props> {
  addDefaultSrc = (e) => {
    e.target.src = this.props.background.replace("maxresdefault", "hqdefault")
  }

  renderVideo = (props) => (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundSize: "contain",
      }}
      className="featured-community-video"
    >
      <img onError={this.addDefaultSrc} src={props.background} alt="" />
      <div className="featured-community-video-title">
        <h2 style={{ fontSize: "0.8em" }}>WATCH</h2>
        <h1 style={{ fontSize: props.titleFontSize }}>{props.title}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        key={this.props.postId}
        style={{
          width: this.props.width,
          height: "50%",
        }}
        className="featured-community-video-container"
      >
        <Link to={routeCodes.POST_DETAILS(this.props.postId)}>
          {this.renderVideo(this.props)}
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, I would suggest rendering the `<img />` based on the state of your `<FeatureVideo/>` component.

You could for instance, create an `Image` object, attempt to load the `background`  image and by this, reliably determine if the image fails to load. On the images success or failure to load, you would then `setState()` on your `<FeaturedVideo/>` component with the appropriate `background` value which would instead be used to rendering you actual `<img/>` element:

```
class FeaturedVideo extends Component<Props> {

  componentDidMount() {

    if(this.props.background) {

      // When component mounts, create an image object and attempt to load background
      fetch(this.props.background).then(response => {
         if(response.ok) {
           // On success, set the background state from background
           // prop
           this.setState({ background : this.props.background })
         } else {        
           // On failure to load, set the "default" background state
           this.setState({ background : this.props.background.replace("maxresdefault", "hqdefault") })
         }
      });
    }
  }

  // Update the function signature to be class method to make state access eaiser
  renderVideo(props) {

    return <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        backgroundSize: "contain",
      }}
      className="featured-community-video">

      {/* Update image src to come from state */}

      <img src={this.state.background} alt="" />
      <div className="featured-community-video-title">
        <h2 style={{ fontSize: "0.8em" }}>WATCH</h2>
        <h1 style={{ fontSize: props.titleFontSize }}>{props.title}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        key={this.props.postId}
        style={{
          width: this.props.width,
          height: "50%",
        }}
        className="featured-community-video-container"
      >
        <Link to={routeCodes.POST_DETAILS(this.props.postId)}>
          {this.renderVideo(this.props)}
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: For some reason, the error is still not triggering. I am getting the 404 errors in the console but the onError method is not firing.

Comment: Strange - just to check, do the values of `this.props.background;` prop match the resource urls that are failing to load in dev console?

Comment: Yeah this is the specific url that is giving me troubles `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pzRDaVxNCj8/maxresdefault.jpg`. As you can see `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/pzRDaVxNCj8/hqdefault.jpg` works just fine. Maybe there is another way to go about it besides the onError method?

Comment: I think the fact that it returns a 404 and also a default blank image, the DOM doesn't think it's an error.

Comment: That's correct - just updated answer, does this help?

Comment: This is close lol, all of the images get changed to `hqdefault` due to every call returning `ok: false` on the response object. And all of the objects are the same, very strange..

Comment: Thanks for the try though, I appreciate it!

Comment: @PBandJ333 hey, just investigating the fetch based approach to see if it can get us any further - may be related to the `cors` header not being supplied?

Comment: yeah I tried adding a header but that didn't work either.

`fetch(this.props.background, {
        mode: "no-cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })`

Comment: Hmm - `headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", }` might be a problem seeing you're actually fetching an image

Comment: `headers: { "Content-Type": "image/jpeg", }` didn't work either :(

Comment: `headers: {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"}` also doesn't work

Comment: can you omit `headers` all together? - also, where do you get the image url's from?

Comment: Yeah leaving them out brings the same response. I am getting the URL's from a mongoDB database which uses the YouTube API.